# SQL Query - Limit Results

Tags: sql

I have query that contains a departmentID. I want the results to not be returned for 2 or 3 departments out of about 25.

```
select  i.personID, c.name, c.departmentID, se.sectionID
from individual i
INNER JOIN Section se ON se.teacherPersonID = i.personID
INNER JOIN Course c ON c.courseID = se.courseID
INNER JOIN Calendar cal ON cal.calendarID = c.calendarID and c.calendarID = 32  INNER JOIN SchoolYear sy on sy.endyear = cal.endyear and sy.active = 1
INNER JOIN activeTrial at ON at.trialID = se.trialID
inner join contact con on con.personID = i.personID
Where c.departmentID is not NULL 
order by c.departmentID
```

Comment: In SQL Server you can use the "TOP(n)" function as in:

SELECT TOP(n) * FROM TABLE

Where n is the number of rows you wants. In Oracle you have to add "WHERE RowNum < n". I don't know in other platforms

Comment: can you clarify some more? you want the result sto "NOT BE RETURNED for 2-3 repartments"? do you have the id of these departments or other data you want to remove them by?

Comment: Why not try `Where IsNull(c.departmentID,-1) not in (-1,2,3,5)`?

Comment: @rualmar I don't think you read OP's question correctly. It seems he doesn't want to limit the number of rows, but exclude certain departmentIDs.  That being said, that's only a guess because this question is missing a lot of helpful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the assumption that you don't want data to show for department ID's 4,5, and 6:

```
WHERE c.departmentID IS NOT NULL AND c.departmentID NOT IN (4, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally instead of hardcoding in the `where` clause you would create a table such as `exclusion_department` and store the excluded IDs there. Then in your query you would left join to that table where the IDs are `NULL`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This will work provided that `c.departmentID` is a key where the first key starts at a non-negative value and increments up.

```
SELECT i.personID, c.name, c.departmentID, se.sectionID
    FROM individual i
    INNER JOIN Section se ON se.teacherPersonID = i.personID
    INNER JOIN Course c ON c.courseID = se.courseID
    INNER JOIN Calendar cal ON cal.calendarID = c.calendarID 
          and c.calendarID = 32  
    INNER JOIN SchoolYear sy on sy.endyear = cal.endyear 
          and sy.active = 1
    INNER JOIN activeTrial at ON at.trialID = se.trialID
    INNER JOIN contact con on con.personID = i.personID
    WHERE IsNull(c.departmentID,-9999) NOT IN (-9999,2,3,5)
    ORDER BY c.departmentID
```